# UICollectionView recording selected items

Tags: objective-c

I have set up a `uicollectionviewcontroller` with a few test items. I now want to select multiple items and then when I go to the next page have it tell me which items were selected. I have seen the method `indexPathforselectedItems` which returns an array but I'm not able to use it, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Be more specific - what happens when you try indexPathforselectedItems? What code do you have so far?

Comment: I haven't got anything yet as I don't know how to implement it (there are absolutely no examples out there). I found a tutorial from app coda using a different method so I might give that a go